# How to give two different action to a FloatingActionButton based on flag

Tags: dart, flutter

I am working on pause and play actions using a floating action button, but one action is happening another action is not happening.

```
              bool video_record = true;

              FloatingActionButton(
              backgroundColor: Colors.red,
              onPressed: (){
                setState(() {
                  _onRecordButtonPressed();
                  if(!video_record){
                    _onStopButtonPressed();
                  }
                });
              }
          ),
```

Comment: can add some more code that would be more helpful. And i don't think you should call `_onRecordButtonPressed` and `_onStopButtonPressed` function in `setState`. take these out from `setState` and try out, also make sure you are changing the `video_record` flag

Comment: I have solved it .Thanks for the solution

Comment: At first How to hide a icon button flutter and while click another button i have to show that again

Comment: please check https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Visibility-class.html. you have to handle the check condition when you are supposed to show and hide UI

Comment: I have a timer of 30 sec i want to pause and start when i click a button in flutter . can you suggest me any solution:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how you should do it.

```
FloatingActionButton(
    backgroundColor: Colors.red,
    onPressed: () {
      _onRecordButtonPressed();
      if (!video_record) {
        _onStopButtonPressed();
      }
      setState(() {
        video_record = !video_record;
      });
    }),
```